# How can I connect multiple tables using an inner join?

Tags: sql

I am trying to select and print customer_name(customer table), room_number(room table), room_rate (room table),rate_type(reservation table), checkin_date(reservation table), checkout_date(reservation table),  billing_amount(billing table) from multiple tables. I tried to do an inner join but the error is 'column ambiguously defined '

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer c 
    INNER JOIN Reservation r 
        ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id 
    INNER JOIN Room s 
        ON s.room_id = r.room_id 
    INNER JOIN billing b 
        ON reservation_id = b.reservation_id 
WHERE c.customer_name = 'John Scott';
```

Comment: Perhaps reservation_id needs to be fully qualified.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson  ok not exactly sure how to fix that error

Comment: Your last JOIN is missing a table name/alias.  `ON reservation_id = b.reservation_id`.  Which table contains `reservation_id` on the left side of the equals sign?  To put it another way, which two tables are you joining there?

Comment: The reservation_id is also in the billing table. So the reservation table and the billing table

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the table alias on the left side of the last JOIN.  Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer c 
    INNER JOIN Reservation r 
        ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id 
    INNER JOIN Room s 
        ON s.room_id = r.room_id 
    INNER JOIN billing b 
        ON r.reservation_id = b.reservation_id 
WHERE c.customer_name = 'John Scott';
```

Comment: output is no data found or no rows selected ??

Answer (score 1):

One problem is in your join and one in your `select`:

```
SELECT * 
-------^ duplicate column names
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN
     Reservation r 
     ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id INNER JOIN
     Room s 
     ON s.room_id = r.room_id INNER JOIN
     billing b 
     ON reservation_id = b.reservation_id 
--------^ missing table alias
WHERE c.customer_name = 'John Scott';
```

If the only duplicate columns are the `JOIN` keys, then the `USING` clause (standard but not supported by all databases) is a handy way to get all the columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN
     Reservation r 
     USING (customer_id) INNER JOIN
     Room s 
     USING (room_id) INNER JOIN
     billing b 
     USING (reservation_id)
WHERE c.customer_name = 'John Scott';
```

When you using `USING`, the key columns are not duplicated with `SELECT *`.

Comment: The issue is that no rows are selected

Comment: @sas1205 . . . Then either there are no matching rows for the `JOIN`s or no customer has that name.